# 100% width on iPhone email

Tags: html, css, email

I am making an HTML email to send from my website when people use the contact form, and with all of the testing I've done, I've managed to squash many bugs, but despite many attempts and plenty of searching around, I can't seem to manage to get my email to take 100% width on iPhone's.

Here's a screenshot of the problem: http://i62.tinypic.com/2r6mh5y.png

And here's a copy of the code I'm using:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body { width: 100% !important; }
            p { font-family: Arial; }
            a { font-family: Arial; }
            td { font-family: Arial; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#000000" style="font-family:Arial; min-width:100%; background-color:#000000; margin:0; padding:0;" topmargin="0">
        <table width="100%" bgcolor="#000000" style="width:100%; background-color:#000000; background-image:url(http://newsite.moninfolettre.ca/images/courriel/top_bg.jpg); background-position:center top; background-repeat:repeat repeat;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="600" height="130" align="center" valign="middle">
                    <img src="http://newsite.moninfolettre.ca/images/courriel/logo_courriel.png" alt="Geant du web - Infolettre" width="168" height="61" style="font-size:18px; font-family:Arial; color:#FFFFFF;" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" bgcolor="#CD0C11" style="width:100%; background-color:#CD0C11" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td height="4" style="font-size:1px;-webkit-text-adjust:none;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table width="100%" bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="width:100%; background-image:url(http://newsite.moninfolettre.ca/images/courriel/shadow.jpg); background-position:center top; background-repeat:repeat no-repeat; background-color:#F2F2F2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="520">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size:32px; padding:20px 0 0; white-space:nowrap;">Votre transaction est</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size:32px; font-weight:900; color:#E30512; padding:0 0 15px; white-space:nowrap;">
                                complétée avec succès !!
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="width:100%; background-color:#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="520" style="padding:20px 0 0; color:#5A5A5A">
                    <p style="margin:0 0 20px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    <p style="margin:20px 0;">Praesent nulla felis, malesuada eu sapien vitae, pretium dictum dolor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam faucibus dui in est euismod, at sollicitudin elit aliquam. Nulla augue ante, tincidunt vel sodales id, tincidunt non nibh.</p>
                    <p style="margin:20px 0;">In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam feugiat aliquam tortor, id vestibulum dui rutrum vel. Nulla tincidunt, tortor vitae iaculis scelerisque, ipsum augue gravida ipsum, ac faucibus mauris urna et tortor.</p>
                    <p style="margin:20px 0;">Duis luctus pretium turpis, sed iaculis mauris commodo at. Aliquam dictum venenatis enim et tincidunt. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed viverra laoreet neque, vel sodales tellus luctus vitae.</p>
                    <p style="margin:20px 0;">Merci d'avoir fait confiance à <strong style="font-weight:900;">GÉANT DU WEB !</strong></p>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="width:100%; background-color:#F2F2F2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="600">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="260" style="padding:30px 0 20px;">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding:0 0 10px;">Accèdez dès maintenant à</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table width="165" height="35" bgcolor="#E30512" style="width:165px; background-color:#E30512; border-radius:10px;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:900; text-transform:uppercase;">
                                                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF;">Votre compte</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding:20px 0 10px;">ou contactez notre équipe:</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color:#5A5A5A;">Sans frais</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-size:24px; font-weight:900; color: #E30512; line-height:100%; padding:0 0 10px;">1-888-86-GÉANT</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color:#5A5A5A;">Montréal</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-size:24px; font-weight:900; color: #E30512; line-height:100%; padding:0 0 20px;">(514) 359-2949</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Besoin de <a href="#" style="font-weight:bold; color:#000000;">Support en ligne</a> ?</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td width="300" valign="bottom" style="padding:0px;">
                                <img src="http://newsite.moninfolettre.ca/images/courriel/robot.jpg" alt="" style="display:block;" width="300" height="280" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table width="100%" bgcolor="#000000" style="width:100%; background-color:#000000; background-image:url(http://newsite.moninfolettre.ca/images/courriel/bottom_bg.jpg); background-position:center top; background-repeat:repeat repeat;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="600" height="100" align="center" valign="middle">
                    <a href="www.moninfolettre.ca" style="font-size:24px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase; color:#FFFFFF;">
                        <span style="color:#FFFFFF;">www.moninfolettre.ca</span>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is the image above : http://newsite.moninfolettre.ca/images/courriel/robot.jpg - Make the image responsive or give a small size

Comment: @LuisP.A. just tried this, it fixed a bug where that image would spill out of the layout, but the email still won't take 100% width.

Comment: I have the exact same problem... Aside form adding a whole swag of media queries and setting pixel widths for the wrapping table, is there any other solution? The media query route is not very future friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Any elements that you want to have a width of 100%, add an addtional a pixel based `min-width`

For example:

```
width: 100%;
min-width: 600px;
```

Or inline with `<table style="min-width: 600px; width: 100%;" width="100%">`

I double up with the width attribute just for that extra surety. You just never know... :)

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Safari's default viewport width is 980px, so it uses 980px as the width of the containing element for your divs. This is why your layout is corrupted.
You can fix this setting the viewport, or by adding min-width:"your body width" of your design in pixels; to your body. Mobile Safari will use the min-width's value for setting its viewport.

to set the viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Just tried this, no visible change, even in conjunction with the proposed fix from Luis P.A.

Comment: doesn't min-width work too? don't set min-width:100% but min-width:something-px;

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a problem on devices with a viewport smaller than 980px?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think yes.

Comment: let me know if it works changing the min-width attribute

Comment: Got it working in conjunction with a media query to target iPhones specifically.